# Create translation post in second language with WPML and REST API in WordPress

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, wpml

I tried to create a post with translation from a remote app with the WordPress REST API.

My first post is already on the website and I have its id (433).

So I tried to do many POST calls where I try to find the good field to fill up:

```
"wpml_current_locale" => "en_US"
"translation_of" => 433
"wpml_translation_of" => 433
```

But I can't find any way.

Which fields should I fill up? There is no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a part of the answer :

To post a translation, we need to put the language code in the endpoint URL

Exemple :

I want to post in English, my endpoint need to be :
https://example.com/en/wp-json/wp/v2/post

And from what i know now (support WPML), it's impossible to link a translation by REST API.
It works just for product (woocommerce) :
https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/using-wordpress-rest-api-woocommerce-multilingual/#create-products

I ask them this feature.